# entity framework two project with share database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

i have two completely difference project site
like :

[adminPanel(asp mvc site),utilities(classLibrary),mobileConnection(asp web api)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrSbl.png)

adminPanel Project and MobileConnection Project has separably authentication but their account has some share field,

Utilities Code (share with two project) :

```
public class MobileApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<MobileApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {       
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class AdminApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Organization organization { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<AdminApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {         
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        return userIdentity;
    }

}
```

admin Project Code :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AdminApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AdminApplicationUser>().ToTable("AdminUser");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AdminRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("AdminUserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AdminUserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("AdminUserLogin");
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Competition> Competitions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }

}
```

mobileConnection Project Code :

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MobileApplicationUser>
 {
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AdminApplicationUser>().ToTable("MobileUser");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("MobileRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("MobileUserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("MobileUserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("MobileUserLogin");
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Competition> Competitions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }

}
```

my profile and organization has relation together,
so... i can`t update database both project and have my goal!
what can i do ?

Comment: i don`t want to have one DbContext and do separate my authorization with Role and users

Comment: Your goal is unclear. What is the end state?

Comment: i want one share database with two ASP MVC Web application(they have separate authentication)

Comment: What does the code that you have shown have to do with that goal?

Answer (score 1):

Assume this is a code first question.
Yes you can have 1 DB Context accessing multiple Databases or  have several DBContexts access 1 database. Managing the migration is the key challenge.

> Bounded DBContext and Entity framework

is a good place to start your research